# VB.Net Dictionary inside of a dictionary adding / removing data

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I'm creating an application where I have different libraries, books and non-book media stored in dictionaries and displayed in listboxes. The user can add and remove additional dictionaries for any of these 3 elements. My issue lies in bringing up the new form to create a link between a library and it's media.

I have a listbox for "Books at Current library" and "Non-Book Media at Current Library" Which will display the media  that is linked to the specific library that is highlighted in the listbox. And the user can freely add and remove different media to the library.

frmManager: https://prnt.sc/mnd8qf

frmAssociationScreen: https://prnt.sc/mnd8sh

I'm trying to create a dictionary within a dictionary that I can manipulate the data with for adding the different media to the individual  libraries. But I'm unsure where to go from here, I'd like to start by hard coding a few links to Zahnow Library and add  a few books as well as one non-book media.

```
Public Class frmManager

    ' Global data structures
    Public Libraries As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Public Books As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Public nonBookMedia As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Public EquippedLibrary As New Dictionary(Of String, LibraryWithMedia)

    Structure LibraryWithMedia

        Dim strLibraryName As String
        Dim dicBooks As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Dim nonBookMedia As Dictionary(Of String, String)

    End Structure

    Private Sub frmManager_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Libraries.Add("SVSU", "Zahnow Library")
        Libraries.Add("BR", "Fleschner Memorial Library")
        Libraries.Add("SDJ", "Scott D. James Technical Repository")

        Books.Add("104", "Data Structures for Fun and Profit")
        Books.Add("103", "Doing More With Less - Naval Lint Art")
        Books.Add("102", "Interpretive Klingon Poetry")
        Books.Add("105", "Programming with the Bidgoli")
        Books.Add("101", "Zen and the Art of Appliance Wiring")

        nonBookMedia.Add("201", "CD - IEEE Computer: the Hits")
        nonBookMedia.Add("203", "DVD - Databases and You: the Video Experience")
        nonBookMedia.Add("202", "DVD - The Pirates of Silicon Valley")

        populatelstLibrary()
        populatelstBooks()
        populatelstBookMedia()

    End Sub

    Sub populatelstLibrary()

        lstLibraries.Items.Clear()

        For Each library In Libraries
            lstLibraries.Items.Add(library.Value & " --- " & library.Key)
        Next

    End Sub
```

How I manipulated the data to delete library dictionary

```
Private Sub btnDeleteLibrary_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeleteLibrary.Click

        Dim key As String = ""
        Dim tmpLibraries As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        ' If an index is selected in listbox then continue
        ' If nothing selected, the button does nothing
        If lstLibraries.SelectedIndex > -1 Then

            If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this library?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel, "Delete confirmation") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

                For Each library In Libraries

                    If lstLibraries.SelectedItem.Equals(library.Value & " --- " & library.Key) Then
                        ' DoNothing
                        ' the selected item is not added to temp library
                    Else
                        ' Add all other values to temp library
                        tmpLibraries.Add(library.Key, library.Value)
                    End If

                Next

                lstLibraries.Items.Clear() ' Clear the list box 
                Libraries = tmpLibraries ' Set dictionary Libraries equal to temp libararies
                tmpLibraries = Nothing ' Set temp library back to nothing
                populatelstLibrary() ' Repopulate the list box

            End If

        End If

    End Sub
```

frmAssociationScreen.vb

```
Public Class frmAssociationScreen

    Private Sub frmAssociationScreen_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        lstAllLibraries.Items.Clear()

        For Each library In frmManager.Libraries
            lstAllLibraries.Items.Add(library.Value & " --- " & library.Key)
        Next

        For Each book In frmManager.Books
            lstAllBooks.Items.Add(book.Value & " --- " & book.Key)
        Next

        For Each nonBook In frmManager.nonBookMedia
            lstAllMedia.Items.Add(nonBook.Value & " --- " & nonBook.Key)
        Next


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnManagerScreen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnManagerScreen.Click
        Me.Close() ' Close current form
        frmManager.Visible = True ' Make manager form visible
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAddBook_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddBook.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRemoveBook_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemoveBook.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub lstAllLibraries_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstAllLibraries.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some slight changes in your code as below:

In your structure **LibraryWithMedia**
We added ***SUB NEW***

```
' Structure of single library
Structure LibraryWithMedia
    '
    Dim strLibraryName As String
    Dim dicBooks As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim nonBookMedia As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    '
    'new library constructor
    Sub New(ByVal LibName As String)
        strLibraryName = LibName
        dicBooks = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        nonBookMedia = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    End Sub
    '
End Structure
```

In your **EquippedLibrary** declaration.

The declaration changed from (string, string) to simply LibraryWithMedia

```
  Public EquippedLibrary As List(Of LibraryWithMedia)
```

At the end/bottom of your **Form_Load** event

```
' construct equipped library and define the library names
EquippedLibrary = New List(Of LibraryWithMedia)
' initialise each library with empty books/media dictionaries
populateEquippedLibNames
```

The **PopulateEquippedLibNames** Subroutines (this is a new subroutine)

```
Sub populateEquippedLibNames()
    '
    Dim Counta As Integer
    Dim tmpSingleLib As LibraryWithMedia
    '
    For Counta = 0 To Libraries.Count - 1
        tmpSingleLib = New LibraryWithMedia(Libraries.Values(Counta))
        EquippedLibrary.Add(tmpSingleLib)
        tmpSingleLib = Nothing
    Next
    '
End Sub
```

And then for adding/removing each book to the SELECTED library in the TOP listbox

```
Private Sub btnAddBook_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddBook.Click
    '
    EquippedLibrary(lstLibraries.SelectedIndex).dicBooks.Add(Books.Keys(lstBooks.SelectedIndex), Books.Values(lstBooks.SelectedIndex))
lstSelectedBooks.Items.Add(lstBooks.SelectedItem)
    '
End Sub

Private Sub btnRemoveBook_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemoveBook.Click
    '
    EquippedLibrary(lstLibraries.SelectedIndex).dicBooks.Remove(Books.Keys(lstBooks.SelectedIndex))
    '
End Sub
```

Note that to add a book/media to a library,
A library MUST BE selected in the TOP listbox
The Book or Media being added must also be selected

No error checking is performed, so you will need to add it (such as a listbox has a selection or not) etc

## Update

I have added the libraries on change code for you below

```
Private Sub lstLibraries_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstLibraries.SelectedIndexChanged
   '
   Dim Counta As Integer
   '
   lstSelectedBooks.Items.Clear()
   lstSelectedMedia.Items.Clear()
   If EquippedLibrary(lstLibraries.SelectedIndex).dicBooks.Count > 0 Then
      For Counta = 0 To EquippedLibrary(lstLibraries.SelectedIndex).dicBooks.Count - 1
         lstSelectedBooks.Items.Add(EquippedLibrary(lstLibraries.SelectedIndex).dicBooks.Keys(Counta) & " --- " & EquippedLibrary(lstLibraries.SelectedIndex).dicBooks.Values(Counta))
      Next
   End If
   Counta = Nothing
'
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Zeddy, you're beyond helpful on a lot of my post haha.

Comment: I'm having an issue with the line `EquippedLibrary(lstLibraries.SelectedIndex).dicBooks.Add(Books.Keys(lstBooks.SelectedIndex), Books.Values(lstBooks.SelectedIndex))` Getting the error `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'` even though the library and book are both selected when I click the `add` button.

Comment: Look at the EquippedLibraries in the watch window, I guess one of the listboxes is named differently from what I wrote

Comment: Yeah you're right, was `lstAllBooks` not getting errors was throwing me off. Now to figure out how to have it update the books based off the selected index. Currently just adds the books to the list box regardless of the index selected.

Comment: change it to -  EquippedLibrary(lstLibraries.SelectedIndex).dicBooks.Add(Books.Keys(lstAllBooks.SelectedIndex), Books.Values(lstAllBooks.SelectedIndex)) - I had it named incorrectly (oops)

Comment: Yeah I did that, however for some reason it doesn't update the actual listbox when changing the library index. It also does not save if I was to close the form to go back to the main `frmManager` and go back to `frmAssociationScreen` the list box becomes empty again. Also, no matter which index is selected the program continues to add the books to the same location.

Comment: Yes unfortunately I did not add those bits since the question was adding/removing data. You just need to update (clear & reload) the list boxes on the left using data from the EquippedLibrary object based on the ListIndex selected in the Top listbox

Comment: In your updated code what does `Dim counta` do in this instance? Isn't it reset back to 0 in the `for loop` every time the index is changed? The code seems to run fine without that there.

Comment: Every time the selected-item in the listbox at the top changes, the event is executed. When the event is executed the Counta variable is used to store the value of the loop instance. Make sure you have OPTION EXPLICIT ON  as the first line in form form class (above everything) That means variables must be declared prior to use, as a rule. If your code runs fine without it maybe you have a variable with the same name, higher up the scope ladder (like globally as opposed to locally)

Comment: @Devin The `Dim counta` would be needed in VBA but isn't needed in .NET where the counting variable for a `For` loop can be declared in the head of the loop.  (And the later set to `Nothing` might have value with an object type in VBA but is pointless in .NET.)

Comment: @Devin In fact, the loop would be better written as a `For Each` loop.  The body would need to be tweaked a little to account for the index variable turning into a key-value pair, but the body currently works on both keys and values.

Comment: @Devin Also, if you're going to iterate over the dictionary, you may not want the normal (hash-based) dictionary, you might want a `SortedDictionary (Of TKey, TValue)` instead.